# Does StreamingOutput in Jersey need to close?

Tags: jersey-2.0, outputstream

I have a snippet to download a file from jersey 2.22,

```
StreamingOutput stream = (OutputStream os) -> {
        try {
            os.write( get a byte array here);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to fetch file, id:" + fileName, e);
            throw new Exception());
        } 
    };
```

the above code is working, but i'm wondering if the output stream I'm writing in needs to close.

I searched jersey's source code, in OutboundMessageContext

```
 public void close() {
    if(this.hasEntity()) {
        try {
            OutputStream e = this.getEntityStream();
            e.flush();
            e.close();
        } catch (IOException var10) {
            Logger.getLogger(OutboundMessageContext.class.getName()).log(Level.FINE, var10.getMessage(), var10);
        } finally {
            if(!this.committingOutputStream.isClosed()) {
                try {
                    this.committingOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException var9) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OutboundMessageContext.class.getName()).log(Level.FINE, var9.getMessage(), var9);
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

this method is to close entity stream. I'm not sure if this is the right close method working with StreamingOutput, can anyone help?

Comment: It is. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: @peeskillet do you mean jersey will close the outputstream with the above close method? I don't really need to close the outputstream myself?

Comment: @peeskillet thank you